# Projectile movement using Box2d.

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I need to know how to use box2d for projectile motion.

initially, projectileTime=0;
then i call the following function for projectile motion. It works pretty good.
But i want to achieve the same thing using box2d. As far as i know Box2d works only with force, it does not encourage placing object directly, So how to use Box2d for projectile movement??

```
-(void)projectilelaunched:(ccTime)dt 
{
    projectileTime+=(5*dt);

    double vh=v*cos(theta);

    x=vh*projectileTime;

    double y = x*tan(theta)- 10*((x/vh)*(x/vh))/2;

    projectile.position=ccp(projectilePositionBeforeLaunched.x + x,projectilePositionBeforeLaunched.y+y);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With box2D, you'd only need to set its initial position and initial velocity (via `applyForce`). Box2d will take care of the rest, applying gravity, stopping when hitting other objects etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can directly set up position of the body by calling:

```
body->SetTransform(vector,angle)
```

Comment: But that requires manually calculating the position, which is kinda weird when you already have the power of physics simulation at your hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
b2Vec2 vector = self.speed * b2Vec2(cos(angle), sin(angle));

self.projectileBody->SetLinearVelocity(vector);
```